How can I get the names of manual snapshots older than 30 days from RDS DB Instances using AWS CLI
I have a working command to fetch manual snapshots info. How can I use the query option to filter out only snapshots older than 30 days?
aws rds describe-db-cluster-snapshots \
--query "DBClusterSnapshots[*].[DBClusterSnapshotIdentifier, DBClusterIdentifier, SnapshotCreateTime, Status, Engine]" \
--output table
Thanks very much

You can try something like this:
aws rds describe-db-cluster-snapshots --query "DBClusterSnapshots[?SnapshotCreateTime<='$(date -v -30d '+%Y-%m-%d')'].[DBClusterSnapshotIdentifier, DBClusterIdentifier, SnapshotCreateTime, Status, Engine]"

Depending on your operating system, it might need to be: date --date='-30 days' '+%Y-%m-%d')
